# Equivalent in C# of PHP's date_create()->format()?

Tags: c#, php, date

In PHP, you can do this:

```
date_diff(date_create('2013-01-27 22:14:44 UTC'), date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s e')))->format('%y year(s), %m month(s), %d day(s), %H hour(s), %i minute(s) and %s second(s)')
```

to get the amount of years, days, months and so on since a date instead of just one of those. Is there a way to do this in c# too? Sorry for the short question

Comment: Take a look at the DateTime class, "c# DateTime" in any search engine should find you the right results.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, Subtracting one `DateTime` object from another gives you a `TimeSpan` structure back.  You'd use `TimeSpan`'s [`.ToString("formathere")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a nicely formatted String from it.

Edit:   One issue you'll have is that TimeSpan doesn't have year or month format strings.  You may want to use @JonSkeet's [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/) instead, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958122/15880).

Answer (score 1):

It is alot simplier to do in c#, you can just use the subtraction operator on two [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)s, the result of which is a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) which contains the number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds of the difference.

```
        DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 27, 22, 14, 44, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan diff = date1 - DateTime.Now;
```

You can then format the output in a number of ways, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) for more format options.

```
        string output = String.Format("{0:dd} day(s), {0:hh} hour(s), {0:mm} minute(s) and {0:ss} second(s)", diff);
```