# Parse timespan issue on 0000-00-00.01:00:00

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm having issues parsing a time span, i have a start and end time for a dataset and the step is formatted like this `0000-00-00.01:00:00` so in this case it's only an hour between. but it might be days etc so it has to keep some support.

The issue is that a line like this

```
const string TimeSpanFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd\.hh\:mm\:ss";
TimeSpan.ParseExact(StepToConvert, TimeSpanFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or like this

```
DateTime.ParseExact(StepToConvert, TimeSpanFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay
```

returns both the error

> Additional information: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

so I'm kind of at a loss, with the exception of making a helper class/structure.
works fine on times like `2013-01-01.00:00:00` for Datetime btw.

Any bright ideas in the community on this?

Comment: This is the min-value for DateTime: `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. Look at your date.

Comment: It might sounds like a stupid question but what's the type of `SpanToConvert`?

Comment: @Thomas: it seems that it's the string mentioned in the first sentence: `0000-00-00.01:00:00`

Comment: Why don't you start at `DateTime.MinValue`?

Comment: @Tim because it is not my dataset sadly so i have to work around what the sensors return.

Answer (score 4):

For `TimeSpan.ParseExact`, there is no [custom timespan format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `yyyy` and `MM`. These are some problematic subjects for a `TimeSpan`. It is just a time interval. [Duration of a month or year depends on a lot of stuff.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957984/format-a-timespan-with-years)

For `DateTime.ParseExact`, first of all, your `0000-00-00.01:00:00` is less than [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx). You can't parse a string that doesn't exist as a `DateTime`. Even if your string is available `DateTime` value, your string and your format doesn't match *at all*. For a string like `2013-01-01.00:00:00`, your `TimeSpanFormat` should be `yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss` and preferable an [`IFormatProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) has `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string s = "2013-01-01.00:00:00";
const string format = "yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss";
DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay // 00:00:00
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted but the core issue of this question seems to be how to parse a `DateTime` `0000-00-00.01:00:00` successfully since OP cant change the fact that it exists and must be interpreted as zero timespan. The only approach that comes to my mind is to check if it's `0000-00-00` and change it to `0001-01-01`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That might be. Changing `0000-00-00` to `0001-01-01` process is provided by OP in his own answer, so I wouldn't dare to change mine :)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with dates, so you can use the "bank" method and count months and years for 30 days and 360 days - or what fits best (if at all needed).

Then do a custom split and calculation and add the pieces:

```
string step = "0001-02-03.01:00:00";

string[] parts = step.Split(new string[] {"-", "."}, StringSplitOptions.None);

TimeSpan hours = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[3]);
TimeSpan days = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[2]), 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan months = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[1]) * 30, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan years = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[0]) * 360, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan total = hours.Add(days).Add(months).Add(years);

Console.WriteLine(total.ToString());
```

Result from the example is 423.04:00:00.