# Type Date in one text box and calculate it

Tags: c#

I write a code in c# for find the birth age. But how can i enter the date in the one only on one text box and calculate the age between the birth date and the current date.help me please !!

Comment: pls show some of your code

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must create a DateTime from the text box text. This can be done with `DateTime.Parse()` or better `DateTime.TryParse()`.

```
string text  = "06/25/2016";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(text);
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - date;
int years = (int)(duration.TotalDays / 365.25);
```

For an exact result also look at [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) like here: [Format A TimeSpan with years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958122/4629491)

Answer (score 0):

```
var birthDateInput = yourTextBox.Text;
DateTime birthDate;

TimeSpan age;

if(DateTime.TryParse(out birthDate))
{
    age = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
}
```

When this is done, if the input string is a valid date then `age` will contain a `TimeSpan` representing the elapsed time. You'd probably want a little more validation. If the user enters a date in the future then the age will be negative.