# C# Formatting TimeSpan to show a date

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm working on a simple program that calculates how old a member is and applies the correct membership fee based on age.

```
        public static DateTime DateTime()
    {
        DateTime birth = new System.DateTime(1991, 9, 20);
        DateTime today = new System.DateTime(2017, 1, 22);
        TimeSpan age = today - birth;
        Console.WriteLine(age);
        return birth;
    }
```

Here is the code I'm using, my return value is

```
9256.00:00:00
```

How can parse this into a more readable yyyy,mm,dd format?

Comment: that format doesn't make sense for a timespan.

Comment: What you are actually wanted to display?

Comment: If you need "age" as understood by most people - number of full years person is alive - you may want to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c which gives result in just years.

Comment: I was looking for a better solution to finding out the number of days since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [nodatime](http://nodatime.org/)

```
var ld1 = new LocalDate(1991, 9, 20);
var ld2 = new LocalDate(2017, 1, 22);
var period = Period.Between(ld1, ld2);

Debug.WriteLine(period.Years);
Debug.WriteLine(period.Months);
Debug.WriteLine(period.Days);
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps me get where I need to be.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957984/format-a-timespan-with-years) has put it:

> TimeSpan has no sensible concept of "years" because it depends on the
>   start and end point.

Why don't you try his [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) instead?

You can manually download [here](http://nodatime.org/)

You can also divide by 365.25 (average number of days in a year), and get the whole number

```
Convert.ToInt32(age.Days / 365.25);
```

Comment: Voting as duplicate is better option when you have nothing to add to existing answer from another question.

Comment: Edited to add a bit to the answer.