# Humanizer for DateTime

Tags: c#, humanizer

I have this code:

```
Configurator.DateTimeHumanizeStrategy = new PrecisionDateTimeHumanizeStrategy(.75);
var dateTime1 = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2).AddMonths(-5);
var text1 = dateTime1.Humanize();
```

In the text1 variable I get "one year from now". But this is not very accurate. Is there any way to get "one year and seven months from now"?

**Update 1:**

Solution @Daniel Hoffman has some problems, for example if my date is in the past:

```
//UtcNow is 11.07.2021
var dateTime6 = new DateTime(2021, 4, 24);
TimeSpan dateTimeSpan6 = dateTime6 - DateTime.UtcNow;
var text6 = dateTime6.Humanize();
string textSpan6 = dateTimeSpan6.Humanize(maxUnit: TimeUnit.Year, precision: 2);
```

then I get "2 months, 11 weeks" which contains basically the same information twice but in different units.

**Update 2:**

I have fixed the problem with dates in the past, by using Duration() method:

```
var timeSpan = date - DateTime.UtcNow;

return timeSpan.Duration().Humanize(maxUnit: TimeUnit.Year, precision: 2, minUnit: TimeUnit.Day);
```

Comment: You could calculate the number of months between the two dates, and if the result is a multiple of 12, display the number of years, and otherwise display the number of month (or years+months).  see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525990/calculating-the-difference-in-months-between-two-dates/1526004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[Edit]:** Using TimeSpan will allow you to specify the precision of your period, but you will lose the ability to have "yesterday" or
> "tomorrow", and it omits the " ago" or " from now", all of which are
> localized.
> A partial workaround would be to use the TimeSpan.Humanize
> method for TimeSpans less than 366 days and DateTime.Humanize
> otherwise. And if it's only going to be used in one language, the user
> can append the appropriate text depending on if the timespan is
> negative.

You can use the precision parameter with a TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan periodFromNow = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2).AddMonths(-5) - DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Then:

```
string myPeriodFromNow = periodFromNow.Humanize(maxUnit: TimeUnit.Year, precision: 2);
```

Other examples:

```
TimeSpan.FromDays(486).Humanize(maxUnit: TimeUnit.Year, precision: 7) => "1 year, 3 months, 29 days" // One day further is 1 year, 4 month
TimeSpan.FromDays(517).Humanize(maxUnit: TimeUnit.Year, precision: 7) => "1 year, 4 months, 30 days" // This month has 30 days and one day further is 1 year, 5 months
```

See also: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-timespan

Answer (score 0):

It seems like its not currently possible in Humanizer to do what you want.

Check out this method [PrecisionHumanize()](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/937e827b8d664ce800b31160e51e8b2eca95fadc/src/Humanizer/DateTimeHumanizeStrategy/DateTimeHumanizeAlgorithms.cs#L48) on line 102, if the amount of days exceeds 365 then only *years* will be returned. And in general it seems like only one type of *length of time* can be returned, there is no *years* and *months* or *minutes* and *seconds*, just the largest **one**.

But check out another library called [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) it might be able to do what you want.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957984/format-a-timespan-with-years) to a different question similar to yours.